# rsync command works but not as a cronjob

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, backup, rsync

This command works if I input in shell in order to backup locally a database file from a remote server with the date appended to each new backup file so they are all different:

```
rsync -avz -Iu --backup developer@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/home/database.sqlite /home/ProdBackups/dbBackup_(date +\%Y\%m\%d\%H\%M\%S).sqlite
```

But when I try running it as a cronjob inside crontab:

```
* * * * * rsync -avz -Iu --backup developer@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/home/database.sqlite /home/ProdBackups/dbBackup_(date +\%Y\%m\%d\%H\%M\%S).sqlite
```

I get this error:

```
Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

To get the `date` to be replaced with formatted date, you need to force execution with '$' around the parenthesis.

```
* * * * * rsync -avz -Iu --backup developer@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/home/database.sqlite /home/ProdBackups/dbBackup_$(date +\%Y\%m\%d\%H\%M\%S).sqlite
```

As an alternative, consider creating a small wrapper script backup.sh, and then execute the backup.sh scripts from the cron

```
# ~/cron/backup.sh
timestamp=$(date '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
rsync -avz -Iu --backup developer@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/home/database.sqlite /home/ProdBackups/dbBackup_$timestamp.sqlite
```

And the cron will be:

```
* * * * * $HOME/cron/backup.sh
```

The advantage is that you can test the backup script, and then execute it as-is from the cron, without having to worry about quoting the date format, etc.